# What models should I try with a time series database?

Tags: classification, time-series, predictive-modeling, data-science-model, data-analysis

I've acquired and cleaned a dataset that shows statistics from every county in New York State during 2010-2019 focusing on the NYS School Aid correlating it to other growth and criminal statistics. [Source](https://data.ny.gov/)

| County | Year | AidAmount | Population | JailPopulation | CrimesReported |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albany | 2010 | 253982539.0 | 304086 | 698 | 20890.0 |
| Albany | 2011 | 227093331.0 | 304596 | 614 | 20290.0 |
| Albany | 2012 | 226720094.0 | 305723 | 622 | 18940.0 |
| Albany | 2013 | 235041459.0 | 306589 | 629 | 17908.0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| Yates | 2016 | 25572768.0 | 25059 | 46 | 623.0 |
| Yates | 2017 | 26203199.0 | 25002 | 42 | 492.0 |
| Yates | 2018 | 26480853.0 | 24951 | 42 | 473.0 |
| Yates | 2019 | 27494973.0 | 24913 | 43 | 351.0 |

I'm trying to answer questions such as does a lower amount of Aid Amount in a county lead to higher illicit rates? Can we predict counties becoming high or low risk overtime?

I've done [some EDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z05vD.jpg) and now I'm trying to learn more about models and their applications, I want to know what kind of models should I use for this dataset.

I know I might use some classification models where I'll create a high risk label for counties that present  >0.7 per capita crimes reported and then use education aid per capita as the training samples.

As for time series models I'm lost on what ARIMA model should I try, I want to predict Aid Amount, population and criminality values

I would appreciate any input you have on this, I would like to learn as many models as possible.

Comment: It might be easier to tell if you show the data with some visualisations instead of a table. Also what have you tried so far? And what were the results?